# sails js cannot change timeout load hook, for bootstrap

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Hello i have some problem with the bootstrap of sails, i need run a function that take approximately a minute in finished, before sails initialize, so tried do, in the bootstrap hook, but i got this error:

```html
warn: Bootstrap is taking unusually long to execute its callback (2000 milliseconds).
Perhaps you forgot to call it?  The callback is the first argument of the function, `cb`.
```

and searching in internet a the solution of the people was that, i have to create:

config/hookTimeout.js

and put inside :

```
 module.exports.hookTimeout = {
  hookTimeout:120000
 }
```

to override the time of load, but still i get the same error, but i figurethat the other hooks had the hookTimeout = 120000, just the bootstrap hook dont.

Answer (score 0):

The field name is `bootstrapTimeout` instead of `hookTimeout` ([see here for more details](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sailsjs/N65anFyM6m0)).

And your config file (with a name as you like) should be as follows (nothing after `module.exports`):

```
module.exports = {
   bootstrapTimeout: 60000, // in millis
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if you call callback in the bootstrap file.

The simples version of config/bootstrap.js should be like next:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {
  cb();
};
```